# AVL tree insertion and deletion of nodes in C

Tags: c, tree

This is my implementation of AVL tree, it works fine. is there any thing that can be improved about addition and deletion procedures specifically when deleting the root,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

typedef struct treenode node;

struct treenode
{
    int value;
    int height;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
};

node *root = NULL;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}

int nodetype(node *ptr,int flag=1)
{
//please ignore the default argument for now
    /*Determines type of node. ex. leaf or internal*/
    if ((ptr->parent == NULL)&&(flag))
    {
        return 1;
        //root
    }
    else if ((ptr->left == NULL) && (ptr->right == NULL))
    {
        return 2;
        //leaf node
    }
    else if (ptr->left == NULL)
    {
        return 3;
        //internal node with right child
    }
    else if (ptr->right == NULL)
    {
        return 4;
        //internal node with left child
    }
    else
    {
        return 5;
        //internal node with left and right childs
    }

}

int childtype(node *ptr)
{
    /*Determine wether ptr is left child of its parent or right child*/
    node *temp = ptr->parent;

    if (temp->left == ptr)
    {
        return 1;
        //left child
    }
    else if (temp->right == ptr)
    {
        return 2;
        //right child
    }
}

node* createnode(int value)
{
    node *ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->left = ptr->right = ptr->parent = NULL;
    ptr->value = value;
    ptr->height = 0;
    return ptr;
}

node* getposition(node *ptr, int value)
{
    /*Return address of the first node having value equal to "value", returns NULL if not found*/
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (value < ptr->value)
    {
        return getposition(ptr->left, value);
    }
    else if (value > ptr->value)
    {
        return getposition(ptr->right, value);
    }
    else
    {
        return (ptr);
    }

}

int getheight(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return ptr->height;

    }
}

int getotherchildheight(node *ptr)
{
    // returns height of sibling of ptr
    int var = childtype(ptr);
    if (var == 1)
    {
        return getheight(ptr->parent->right);
    }
    else
    {
        return getheight(ptr->parent->left);
    }
}

void setheight(node *start,node *stop=NULL)
{
    //sets height of nodes beggining from start to stop(excluding)
    while (start != stop)
    {
        start->height=max(getheight(start->right),getheight(start->left))+1;
        start = start->parent;
    }

}

int getbalfac(node *ptr)
{
    //Returns balance factor of a node
    return (-(getheight(ptr->left)) + (getheight(ptr->right)));
}

bool isleftheavy(node *ptr)
{
    if (getheight(ptr->left)>getheight(ptr->right))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool isrightheavy(node *ptr)
{
    if (getheight(ptr->right)>getheight(ptr->left))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool isunbalanced(node *ptr)
{
    //Returns true if ptr is unbalanced false otherwise
    int var = getbalfac(ptr);
    if ((var < -1) || (var > 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool isheightchanged(node *ptr)
{
//checks if height of ptr is changed

    int first = ptr->height;
    int second = max(getheight(ptr->left), getheight(ptr->right)) + 1;

    if (first == second)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void rotateright(node *ptr)
{
    node *new_root = ptr->left;
    ptr->left = new_root->right;

    if (ptr->left)
    {
        ptr->left->parent = ptr;
    }

    new_root->right = ptr;

    node *father = ptr->parent;
    if (!father)
    {
        root = new_root;
        new_root->parent = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        int var = childtype(ptr);
        if (var == 1)
        {
            father->left = new_root;
        }
        else
        {
            father->right = new_root;
        }
        new_root->parent = father;
    }
    ptr->parent = new_root;

}

void rotateleft(node *ptr)
{
    node *new_root = ptr->right;
    ptr->right = new_root->left;

    if (ptr->right != NULL)
    {
        ptr->right->parent = ptr;
    }

    new_root->left = ptr;

    node *father = ptr->parent;
    if (father == NULL)
    {
        root = new_root;
        new_root->parent = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        int var = childtype(ptr);
        if (var == 1)
        {
            father->left = new_root;
        }
        else
        {
            father->right = new_root;
        }
        new_root->parent = father;
    }
    ptr->parent = new_root;
}

void rearrange(node *ptr)
{
    if (isleftheavy(ptr))
    {
        if (isrightheavy(ptr->left))
        {
            ptr->left->right->height++;
            ptr->height -= 2;
            ptr->left->height--;
            rotateleft(ptr->left);
            rotateright(ptr);

        }
        else 
        {
            ptr->height -= 2;
            rotateright(ptr);


        }
    }
    else if (isrightheavy(ptr))
    {
        if (isleftheavy(ptr->right))
        {
            ptr->right->left->height++;
            ptr->height -= 2;
            ptr->right->height--;
            rotateright(ptr->right);
            rotateleft(ptr);
        }
        else 
        {
            ptr->height -= 2;
            rotateleft(ptr);

        }
    }
}

void balance(node *ptr)
{
    if (isheightchanged(ptr->parent))
    {
        while ((ptr)&&(!isunbalanced(ptr)))
        {
            setheight(ptr, ptr->parent);
            ptr = ptr->parent;
        }

        if (ptr)
        {
            setheight(ptr, ptr->parent);
            rearrange(ptr);
        }
    }
}

void add(node *ptr, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        node *temp = createnode(value);
        root = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        node *prev = NULL;
        bool flag = true;
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            if (value < ptr->value)
            {
                flag = true;
                prev = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->left;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = false;
                prev = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->right;
            }
        }

        node *temp = createnode(value);
        temp->parent = prev;
        if (flag)
        {
            prev->left = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->right = temp;
        }

        balance(temp);
    }
}

void delntype1()
{//deletes root 
    int var = nodetype(root, 0);
    node *temp = NULL;
    switch (var)
    {
    case 2:
        // root is leaf
        free(root);
        root = NULL;
        break;
    case 3:
        //root has only right child
        temp = root->right;
        free(root);
        root = temp;
        break;

    case 4:
        //root has only left child
        temp = root->left;
        free(root);
        root = temp;
        break;
    case 5:
        //root has both childs
        if (root->left->right)
        {
            node *run = root->left->right;
            while (run->right)
            {
                run = run->right;
            }
            root->value = run->value;
            rm(run);
        }
        else if (root->right->left)
        {
            node *run = root->right->left;
            while (run->left)
            {
                run = run->left;
            }
            root->value = run->value;
            rm(run);
        }
        else
        {
            int var = getbalfac(root);
            temp = root;
            if (var == 1)
            {
                root = root->right;
                root->left = temp->left;
            }
            else if (var == -1)
            {
                root = root->left;
                root->right = temp->right;
            }
            else
            {
                root = root->left;
                root->right = temp->right;
                root->height++;
            }
            free(temp);
        }
        break;


    }
}

void delntype2(node *ptr)
{
    //this function deletes a leaf node
    node *temp = ptr->parent;
    int var = childtype(ptr);

    if (var == 1)
    {
        temp->left = NULL;
    }
    else if (var == 2)
    {
        temp->right = NULL;
    }

    free(ptr);

}

void delntype3(node *ptr)
{
    //this function deletes a internal node having only right child
    node *temp = ptr->parent;
    int var = childtype(ptr);
    if (var == 1)
    {
        temp->left = ptr->right;
    }
    else if (var == 2)
    {
        temp->right = ptr->right;
    }
    ptr->right->parent = temp;
    free(ptr);
}

void delntype4(node *ptr)
{
    //this function delete an internal node having only left child
    node *temp = ptr->parent;
    int var = childtype(ptr);
    if (var == 1)
    {
        temp->left = ptr->left;
    }
    else if (var == 2)
    {
        temp->right = ptr->left;
    }
    ptr->left->parent = temp;
    free(ptr);
}

void delntype5(node *ptr)
{
    //this function deletes an internal node having left and right childs
    node *temp = ptr->parent;
    node *start = NULL;
    int var = childtype(ptr);

    if (var == 1)
    {
        temp->left = ptr->right;
        temp->left->parent = temp;
        node *branch = ptr->left;

        node *run = ptr->right;
        while (run->left != NULL)
        {
            run = run->left;
        }

        run->left = branch;
        branch->parent = run;
        free(ptr);
        start = branch;
    }
    else if (var == 2)
    {
        temp->right = ptr->right;
        temp->right->parent = temp;
        node *branch = ptr->left;

        node *run = ptr->right;
        while (run->left != NULL)
        {
            run = run->left;
        }

        run->left = branch;
        branch->parent = run;
        free(ptr);
        start = branch;
    }
    setheight(start,temp);
}

void rm(node *ptr)
{
    /*Deletes node given by "ptr"*/
    int var = nodetype(ptr);
    node *temp = ptr->parent;

    switch (var)
    {
    case 1:
        delntype1();
        break;
    case 2:
        delntype2(ptr);
        break;
    case 3:
        delntype3(ptr);
        break;
    case 4:
        delntype4(ptr);
        break;
    case 5:
        delntype5(ptr);
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }

    if (temp)
    {
        if (isheightchanged(temp))
        {
            setheight(temp);
        }
        while (temp)
        {
            if (isunbalanced(temp))
            {
                rearrange(temp);
                setheight(temp);
            }
            temp = temp->parent;
        }
    }
}

void inorder(node *ptr)
{
    /*Performs inorder traversal of tree*/
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        inorder(ptr->left);
        printf(" %d", ptr->value);
        inorder(ptr->right);
    }
}

void postorder(node *ptr)
{
    //Performs post order traversal of tree rooted at ptr
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        postorder(ptr->left);
        postorder(ptr->right);
        printf(" %d", ptr->value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted a follow up [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135503/avl-tree-insertion-and-deletion-of-nodes-in-c-2-0#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**childtype**

This gives me a compiler warning because not all paths return a value.  In reality, this shouldn't be triggered, since the parent *should* have a child pointer, however you should make this explicit in the code.  There's no need for the else, if you're not the left child, you must be the right, or something is wrong:

```
if (temp->left == ptr)
{
    return 1;
}
return 2;
```

**Magic numbers**

In the code above, you're returning 1 or 2 to identify the child type.  This doesn't have an obvious association, so you should think about replacing them with a const/#define to make their meaning more obvious to the reader.

**Function visibility**

At the moment, all of your functions can be imported into other modules and called.  Consider if that's really what you want, my view would be it isn't.  Decide on what you think the API to your code should be.  Put relevant function and type declarations into a header and mark the rest of your functions as static to indicate that you don't want them exportable.

**Function order**

You're calling `rm` before the function has been defined.  This means that the compiler is inferring the interface, by the way that you issue the call.  I'd consider changing the function declaration order so that `rm` is defined higher, or adding a function prototype to the top of the file:

```
void rm(node *ptr);
```

**Globals**

Your tree seems to be built around a global parameter `root`.  This effectively limits you to only having one tree in your application at a time.  Collections are quite common, so this seems like a restriction that will cause issues in the future.

**Example usage**

As an extension of defining the API for your code, it would be helpful in future to include an example of how to use your code.  I had a stab at creating a list...  It looked like maybe the way to start was with the `add` method.  This accepts two parameters a `node*` and a value to add.  From what I can tell, the first time you call this, it ignores the `node*`, assuming that you want to create a new list using the global `root` pointer, so you can pass node as NULL.  The second you call it however it uses node so if you pass it as NULL it crashes.  This is somewhat inconsistent.  With that in mind, your **public** api should perform some kind of validation to make sure it's being called correctly.

Some example calls:

```
add(NULL, 5);
add(createnode(3), 3);
add(NULL, 10);
add(createnode(15), 15);
```

Comment: Thanks. originally i was having one more struct for tree which would hold root . but in that case tree* must be passed to every method which  may require to update the root. that is why i am using global root for time being.

Comment: one more question. should i update my code as i improve it or editing the question after posting is bad @forsvarir

Comment: @Balraj editing the question after you have answers is generally frowned on, because it breaks the q&a style.  However, posting follow-up questions with improved code for another review is very welcome (it also tends to get more eyes looking at your code which is always good)

Answer (score 3):

1. `if (x) return true; else return false;` looks better as `return x;`
2. Left/right operations are symmetric so do not need cut/paste. It should be possible to factor out 'small rotation' and 'large rotation' and express all other operations on the tree in terms of these. Switch statement will disappear too.