# AVL tree insertion and deletion of nodes in C. 2.0

Tags: algorithm, c, tree

I asked a question yesterday, based on the answers to that question and some personal insights I was able to update the original code. which I am posting here to get reviewed. I also thought about posting it as an answer to my own question but since that will not provide any more inputs to improve the code, I am posting a new question.

So I believe this code now provides a good AVL tree implementation with basic functions.  Any feedback is welcome.

**HEADER FILE**

```
#ifndef HEADER

typedef struct mytree tree;
typedef struct treenode node;

// constants for nodetype

#define TYPEONE 1 // root node
#define TYPETWO 2 // leaf node
#define TYPETHREE 3 //internal node with only right child
#define TYPEFOUR 4 //internal node with only left child
#define TYPEFIVE 5 //internal node with both childs

//constants for child type

#define LEFTCHILD 1
#define RIGHTCHILD 2

//constant for getheight
#define NULLHEIGHT -1

tree * new_tree();

node * getposition(node * ptr, int value);

node * parent(tree * obj, int value);

bool isempty(tree * obj);

node * leftchild(tree * obj, int value);

node * rightchild(tree * obj, int value);

void add(tree * obj, int value);

void rmroot(tree * obj);

void rmnode(tree * obj, int value);

void searchvalue(tree * obj, int value);

void inorder(tree * obj);

void postorder(tree * obj);

static void posttraverse(node * ptr);

static void intraverse(node * ptr);

static void rem(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static node * createnode(int value);

static int getheight(node * ptr);

static void setheight_toroot(node * ptr);

static void setheight(node * start, node * stop);

static int getbalfac(node * ptr);

static node * findpredecessor(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static bool isleftheavy(node * ptr);

static bool isrightheavy(node * ptr);

static bool isunbalanced(node * ptr);

static bool isheightchanged(node * ptr);

static void rotateright(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static void rotateleft(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static void rearrange(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static void balance(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static void delntype1(tree * obj);

static void delntype2(node * ptr);

static void delntype3(node * ptr);

static void delntype4(node * ptr);

static void delntype5(tree * obj, node * ptr);

static int findmax(int a, int b);

static int roottype(node * ptr);

static int nodetype(node * ptr);

static int findtype(node * ptr, int flag);

static int childtype(node * ptr);


#endif
```

**AVL.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include "newAVL.h"

struct treenode
{
    int value;
    int height;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
};

struct mytree
{
    node *root;
    bool status;
};

// functions provided by ADT

tree* new_tree()
{
    // constructor function for tree
    tree *temp = (tree*)malloc(sizeof(tree));
    temp->root = NULL;
    temp->status = true;
    return temp;
}

node* getposition(node *ptr, int value)
{
    /*Return address of the node having value equal to "value", returns NULL if not found
    ptr should be root of tree*/
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (value < ptr->value)
    {
        return getposition(ptr->left, value);
    }
    else if (value > ptr->value)
    {
        return getposition(ptr->right, value);
    }
    else
    {
        return (ptr);
    }

}

node* parent(tree *obj, int value)
{
    //Returns parent of "ptr"
    node *ptr = getposition(obj->root, value);
    if (ptr)
    {
        return ptr->parent;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

bool isempty(tree *obj)
{
    return obj->status;
}

node* leftchild(tree *obj, int value)
{
    //Returns leftchild of "ptr"
    node *ptr = getposition(obj->root, value);
    if (ptr)
    {
        return ptr->left;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

node* rightchild(tree *obj, int value)
{
    //Returns right child of "ptr"
    node *ptr = obj->root;
    if (ptr)
    {
        return ptr->right;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void add(tree *obj, int value)
{
    // adds "value" to the tree, value must not be a member of set S. where S is set of all values
    // stored in tree

    if (obj->root == NULL)
    {
        node *temp = createnode(value);
        obj->root = temp;
        obj->status = false;
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr = obj->root;
        node *prev = NULL;
        bool flag = true;
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            if (value < ptr->value)
            {
                flag = true;
                prev = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->left;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = false;
                prev = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->right;
            }
        }

        node *temp = createnode(value);
        temp->parent = prev;
        if (flag)
        {
            prev->left = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->right = temp;
        }

        balance(obj, temp);
    }
}

void rmroot(tree *obj)
{
    //Removes root node of tree
    if (obj->root)
    {
        rem(obj, obj->root);
    }
}

void rmnode(tree *obj, int value)
{
    //Removes node having value equal to "value" . no operation is performed if such a node is not found
    node *temp = getposition(obj->root, value);
    if (temp)
    {
        rem(obj, temp);
    }
}

void searchvalue(tree *obj, int value)
{
    //search the tree for value
    node *temp = getposition(obj->root, value);
    if (temp)
    {
        printf("\n\nValue found\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nValue not found\n\n");
    }
}

void inorder(tree *obj)
{
    /*Performs inorder traversal of tree*/
    node *ptr = obj->root;
    printf("\nInorder Traversal : ");
    intraverse(ptr);
    printf("\n\n");

}

void postorder(tree *obj)
{
    //Performs post order traversal of tree rooted at ptr
    printf("\nPostorder Traversal : ");
    node *ptr = obj->root;
    posttraverse(ptr);
    printf("\n\n");
}


// Helper functions for the ADT functions

static void posttraverse(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        posttraverse(ptr->left);
        posttraverse(ptr->right);
        printf(" %d", ptr->value);
    }
}

static void intraverse(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        intraverse(ptr->left);
        printf(" %d", ptr->value);
        intraverse(ptr->right);
    }
}

static void rem(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    /*Deletes node given by "ptr"*/

    int var = nodetype(ptr);
    node *father = ptr->parent;

    switch (var)
    {
    case TYPEONE:
        delntype1(obj);
        break;
    case TYPETWO:
        delntype2(ptr);
        break;
    case TYPETHREE:
        delntype3(ptr);
        break;
    case TYPEFOUR:
        delntype4(ptr);
        break;
    case TYPEFIVE:
        delntype5(obj, ptr);
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }

    if (father)
    {
        if (isheightchanged(father))
        {
            setheight_toroot(father);
        }
        while (father)
        {
            if (isunbalanced(father))
            {
                rearrange(obj, father);
                setheight_toroot(father);
            }
            father = father->parent;
        }
    }
}

static node* createnode(int value)
{
    node *ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->left = ptr->right = ptr->parent = NULL;
    ptr->value = value;
    ptr->height = 0;
    return ptr;
}

static int getheight(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return NULLHEIGHT;
    }
    else
    {
        return ptr->height;
    }
}

static void setheight_toroot(node *ptr)
{
    setheight(ptr, NULL);
}

static void setheight(node *start, node *stop)
{
    //sets height of nodes beggining from start to stop(excluding)
    while (start != stop)
    {
        start->height = findmax(getheight(start->right), getheight(start->left)) + 1;
        start = start->parent;
    }

}

static int getbalfac(node *ptr)
{
    //Returns balance factor of a node
    if (ptr)
    {
        return (-(getheight(ptr->left)) + (getheight(ptr->right)));
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

static node* findpredecessor(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        node *run = ptr->left;
        node *father = ptr->parent;
        if (run)
        {
            while (run->right)
            {
                run = run->right;
            }
        }
        else if ((father) && (ptr->value > father->value))
        {
            run = ptr->parent;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ptr->value > obj->root->value)
            {
                run = obj->root;
            }
            else
            {
                run = NULL;
            }
        }
        return run;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

static bool isleftheavy(node *ptr)
{
    return (getheight(ptr->left) > getheight(ptr->right));
}

static bool isrightheavy(node *ptr)
{
    return (getheight(ptr->right) > getheight(ptr->left));
}

static bool isunbalanced(node *ptr)
{
    //Returns pointer to the first node which is unbalanced
    int var = getbalfac(ptr);
    if ((var < -1) || (var > 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static bool isheightchanged(node *ptr)
{
    int first = ptr->height;
    int second = findmax(getheight(ptr->left), getheight(ptr->right)) + 1;

    if (first == second)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

static void rotateright(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    node *new_root = ptr->left;
    ptr->left = new_root->right;

    if (ptr->left)
    {
        ptr->left->parent = ptr;
    }

    new_root->right = ptr;

    node *father = ptr->parent;
    if (!father)
    {
        obj->root = new_root;
        new_root->parent = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        int var = childtype(ptr);
        if (var == LEFTCHILD)
        {
            father->left = new_root;
        }
        else
        {
            father->right = new_root;
        }
        new_root->parent = father;
    }
    ptr->parent = new_root;

}

static void rotateleft(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    node *new_root = ptr->right;
    ptr->right = new_root->left;

    if (ptr->right)
    {
        ptr->right->parent = ptr;
    }

    new_root->left = ptr;

    node *father = ptr->parent;
    if (!father)
    {
        obj->root = new_root;
        new_root->parent = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        int var = childtype(ptr);
        if (var == LEFTCHILD)
        {
            father->left = new_root;
        }
        else
        {
            father->right = new_root;
        }
        new_root->parent = father;
    }
    ptr->parent = new_root;
}

static void rearrange(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    if (isleftheavy(ptr))
    {
        if (isrightheavy(ptr->left))
        {
            ptr->left->right->height++;
            ptr->height -= 2;
            ptr->left->height--;
            rotateleft(obj, ptr->left);
            rotateright(obj, ptr);
        }

        else
        {
            ptr->height -= 2;
            rotateright(obj, ptr);
        }
    }

    else if (isrightheavy(ptr))
    {
        if (isleftheavy(ptr->right))
        {
            ptr->right->left->height++;
            ptr->height -= 2;
            ptr->right->height--;
            rotateright(obj, ptr->right);
            rotateleft(obj, ptr);
        }

        else
        {
            ptr->height -= 2;
            rotateleft(obj, ptr);
        }
    }
}

static void balance(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    if (isheightchanged(ptr->parent))
    {
        while ((ptr) && (!isunbalanced(ptr)))
        {
            setheight(ptr, ptr->parent);
            ptr = ptr->parent;
        }

        if (ptr)
        {
            setheight(ptr, ptr->parent);
            rearrange(obj, ptr);
        }
    }
}

static void delntype1(tree *obj)
{
    int var = roottype(obj->root);
    node *temp = NULL;
    switch (var)
    {
    case TYPETWO:
        // root is leaf
        free(obj->root);
        obj->root = NULL;
        obj->status = true;
        break;

    case TYPETHREE:
        //root has only right child
        temp = obj->root->right;
        free(obj->root);
        obj->root = temp;
        obj->root->parent = NULL;
        break;

    case TYPEFOUR:
        //root has only left child
        temp = obj->root->left;
        free(obj->root);
        obj->root = temp;
        obj->root->parent = NULL;
        break;

    case TYPEFIVE:
        //root has both childs
        delntype5(obj, obj->root);
        break;
    }
}

static void delntype2(node *ptr)
{
    //this function deletes a leaf node
    node *father = ptr->parent;
    int var = childtype(ptr);

    if (var == LEFTCHILD)
    {
        father->left = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        father->right = NULL;
    }

    free(ptr);

}

static void delntype3(node *ptr)
{
    //this function deletes a internal node having only right child
    node *father = ptr->parent;
    int var = childtype(ptr);
    if (var == LEFTCHILD)
    {
        father->left = ptr->right;
    }
    else
    {
        father->right = ptr->right;
    }
    ptr->right->parent = father;
    free(ptr);
}

static void delntype4(node *ptr)
{
    //this function delete an internal node having only left child
    node *father = ptr->parent;
    int var = childtype(ptr);
    if (var == LEFTCHILD)
    {
        father->left = ptr->left;
    }
    else 
    {
        father->right = ptr->left;
    }
    ptr->left->parent = father;
    free(ptr);
}

static void delntype5(tree *obj, node *ptr)
{
    node *temp = findpredecessor(obj, ptr);
    int var = temp->value;
    rmnode(obj, temp->value);
    ptr->value = var;
}


static int findmax(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}

static int roottype(node *ptr)
{
    return findtype(ptr, 0);
}

static int nodetype(node *ptr)
{
    return findtype(ptr, 1);
}

static int findtype(node *ptr, int flag)
{
    /*Determines type of node. ex. leaf or internal*/
    if ((ptr->parent == NULL) && (flag))
    {
        return TYPEONE;
        //root
    }
    else if ((ptr->left == NULL) && (ptr->right == NULL))
    {
        return TYPETWO;
        //leaf node
    }
    else if (ptr->left == NULL)
    {
        return TYPETHREE;
        //internal node with right child
    }
    else if (ptr->right == NULL)
    {
        return TYPEFOUR;
        //internal node with left child
    }
    else
    {
        return TYPEFIVE;
        //internal node with left and right childs
    }

}

static int childtype(node *ptr)
{
    /*Determine wether ptr is left child of its parent or right child*/
    node *temp = ptr->parent;
    if (temp)
    {
        if (temp->left == ptr)
        {
            return LEFTCHILD;
        }
        else
        {
            return RIGHTCHILD;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    tree *obj = new_tree();
    for (int i = 0;i < 50;i++)
    {
        add(obj, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < 40;i++)
    {
        rmroot(obj);
    }

    inorder(obj);
    postorder(obj);

    searchvalue(obj, 91);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is original [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135375/avl-tree-insertion-and-deletion-of-nodes-in-c)

Comment: In function getheight() NULLHEIGHT is not defined. This makes it broken code. Please define NULLHEIGHT so I can review the code.

Comment: sorry about that. fixed it @pacmaninbw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall the code is very readable. The function names and variable names are generally descriptive, which is a good thing. The indentation is great, The level of comments are pretty
good, although AVL.c could use a description of what it provides and how it provides it. I would replace the use of obj and ptr in your functions
with more meaningful variable names. The function name `add()` isn't descriptive enough, what are you adding?

**Additional Things to Learn**
I suggest that you learn about make and/or cmake if you are not using visual studio. The main() function should be in it's own C file.
The AVL.c file should only contain the functions that implement and modify the tree. The static functions you use should only be in AVL.c and
should not be in the header file. If the functions that use the tree need access to the struct, then the struct should be declared as part
of the typedef.

**Named Constants**
Have constants defined is really good practice. One flaw in the code is the constant naming.

Constants should be named using WORD1_WORD2 rather than WORD1WORD2, see the C coding standard at [Coding Standard](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CCodingStandard.html#gconstants).

The named constants can probably have more meaningful names:

1. TYPEONE could be ROOT_NODE
2. TYPETWO could be LEAF_NODE
3. TYPETHREE could be INTERNAL_NODE_NO_LEFT_CHILD

**Reduce Function Complexity**
The `add()` function is very long, and some parts of it, such as the while (ptr != NULL) loop might be useful to other functions you write.
Consider creating a function/subroutine just for that code. [This Programmers Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166884/should-i-extract-specific-functionality-into-a-function-and-why) discusses when is it good to break up a function, and points to a good reference book.

**Naming Conventions**
There are a number of ways to differentiate words in a variable name or function name, [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) is one of them. An
example of CamelCase is getPosition(). Using one of these conventions helps make the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

**Header Guards**

You've almost done a header guard at the top of your header file:

```
#ifndef HEADER
```

However, you've never actually defined `HEADER`, so if you include it again the code will still be included.  Header guards are typically include the filename in some to make them unique.  In your case I'd expect something like this:

```
#ifndef NEWAVL_H
#define NEWAVL_H

/* Rest of header file */

#endif /* NEWAVL_H */
```

**Casting - `malloc`**

Unnecessary casting is considered bad.  `malloc` returns a `void*`, which is assignable to any pointer, so you don't need to cast it.  Instead of:

```
node *ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You can simply do:

```
node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

**Naming**

I agree with @pacmaninbw, that your variable naming in particular could be better.  Naming is often hard, however using good variable names goes a long way to making your code self documenting.

For example in your `add` method, replacing `flag` with `addNewNodeToLeft` (or similar) would make this much more descriptive:

```
if (flag)
{
    prev->left = temp;
}
else
{
    prev->right = temp;
}
```

**`malloc` - Check for failure**

It's possible for malloc to fail to allocate memory, in which case it returns a NULL pointer.  You're not currently checking it's return value, as a result it's possible that you could end up dereferencing a NULL pointer.  You are better off checking the result of the memory allocation and then deciding a cleaner way to deal with the problem (`new_tree` could itself return NULL for example if it failed to allocate memory for the tree, or you could implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26844703/592182)).

**Parameter validation**

This is perhaps subjective, however I prefer to validate parameters along the public interface (the methods advertised in the header) for my code.  So I would prefer to check in `add` that `obj` isn't NULL.  However, you can't do that because of...

**Black hole methods**

Methods that don't tell you if they've worked or not are OK in languages like C++ and Java, which support exceptions.  If the method doesn't throw an exception you can assume that it has worked successfully.  This isn't really the case with C.  If you don't provide a method for the caller to know that the method has succeeded or failed then they have to blindly assume it went OK.  Currently, if you call `add`, there's no way to notify the caller if the object isn't added to the list.  There's no way for `rmnode` to tell the caller that they've asked to remove an item that wasn't actually in the list, `searchvalue` can't tell the caller if it found the value in the list etc.

**Decide on your public interface**

At the moment, you define node in your header as:

```
typedef struct treenode node;
```

This is fine if the client never needs to do anything with node other than pass pointers around.  If it needs to do more (such as access the member variables, then you need to include the whole definition of the struct in the header).  If on the other hand your clients don't need to know the contents then think about why you're putting them in your public interface at all.  For example these functions seem like they should be static and hidden (since the caller can't do anything with a node, it's just an implementation detail):

```
node * getposition(node * ptr, int value);
node * parent(tree * obj, int value);
node * leftchild(tree * obj, int value);
node * rightchild(tree * obj, int value);
```

**Usefulness**

The core of your tree seems functional and does what you'd expect it to do.  It feels very much like it has been built as a learning exercise.  It can only be applied to a single problem, where it prints the outputs to the console.  Consider extending it so that it supports more useful functionality.  One way of doing that would be to update some of your functions to allow you to supply function pointers.  So, for example you could update your `inorder` method to allow a function pointer like so:

```
typedef void(*value_callback)(int);
void inorder(tree * obj, value_callback callback) {
    intraverse2(ptree->root, callback);
}

static void intraverse(node *ptr, value_callback callback)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        intraverse(ptr->left, callback);
        callback(ptr->value); /* Invoke callback (once per node) */
        intraverse(ptr->right, callback);
    }
}
```

You could then call it like this to print the nodes:

```
inorder(obj, &print_node);
```

Where:

```
void print_node(int value) {
    printf(" %d", value);
}
```

This achieves essentially the same thing as your existing code, but it allows `print_nodes` to be substituted for other operations that you might want to run on each value in the list.